# nested repeater control link button not working in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

nested repeater link button in .ascx page

my code:

```
   <asp:Repeater ID="rptrCategory" DataSourceID="dsCollections" runat="server" >                   
     <ItemTemplate>   
        <li id="l1" runat="server"  class='<%#Eval("CategName") %>'>                                                             
        <asp:Repeater id="rptrTypes" DataSourceID="dsTypes" runat="server"   >                                       
          <ItemTemplate> 
            <li id="current">
            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" style="color:#000; text-decoration:none;"  OnClick="LinkButton1_Click"><%# Eval("SubCategName")%></asp:LinkButton>

          </ItemTemplate>                                        
        </asp:Repeater>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsTypes" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:csConnectionString %>"
        SelectCommand="SELECT SubCategory.SubCategName,Category.CategName, SubCategory.Id, SubCategory.CategId FROM Category INNER JOIN SubCategory ON Category.Id = SubCategory.CategId where Category.Id= @categ">
          <SelectParameters>                
            <asp:ControlParameter Name="categ" ControlID="hfId" PropertyName="Value" />
          </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>   
     </ItemTemplate>                        
   </asp:Repeater>
   <asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsCollections" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:csConnectionString %>"
         SelectCommand="SELECT [CategName], [Id] FROM [Category]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

asp.net code:

protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

```
    Response.Redirect("index.aspx");
}
```

Comment: Add some details to the question, to actually make it a question. For example what exactly is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Did you wrote this on server side

```
Protected Void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

//Your server side code

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must try Button instead of Linkbutton..Button is Working properly in nested repeater..